# How to correctly lock Object for extention method call in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, locking

What differance below two locking ways is going to make. I am doubtful on significance of this way of locking as using exention method and want to understand the internal working.

```
          public static int DoJob(this MapperClass Mapper)
    {
        object MyLock = new object();

        lock (MyLock)
            {
                if (Mapper.MapId != null)
                {
                    //Do some Work
                }
                else                    
                {
                    //Do something else
                }
            }
        }
```

Calling Method:

```
    private void InvokeDoJob(List<MapperClass> Mapper)
    {
        Mapper.ForEach(item =>
        {
           item.DoJob();
        });
    }
```

and this InvokeDojob is calling on multithreading model.

Suggest me how locking would be done and is this the right approach.

Also what difference below code is making. I see locking done on class level only.

```
            class Department
                {
                    Object thisLock = new Object();
                    int salary;
                    Random r = new Random();
                    public Department(int initial)
                    {
                        salary = initial;
                    }
                    int Withdraw(int amount)
                    {
                        lock (thisLock)
                        {
                            if (salary >= amount)
                            {
                                //Console.WriteLine("salary before Withdrawal :  " + salary);
                                return amount = 10;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return amount = 20;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I'm going to state an absolute which I rarely do, but feel fairly confident in this case: locking on a newly created object in a local variable is *always* wrong. It's not protecting anything, because every caller gets a *different* lock object.

Comment: The first lock is completely useless, since the object used for locking isn't shared. For the second lock, it depends where/how the `Withdraw` method is used

Comment: `Suggest me how locking would be done and is this the right approach.` It depends on what you intend to do. I don't see a single thread in the code you gave us, so there's absolutely no need for locking. We need more information

Comment: @KevinGosse - Actually the InvokeDojob is being called on multithreading model. I am figuring out what difference it makes if I declare below at class level Vs at a method level and why.

Comment: `Actually the InvokeDojob is being called on multithreading model.` It is key that your code in your question accurately represents your real problem domain. If multithreading is important to your problem, be sure to include that multithreading code **in** your question.